# ASP.NET Core publish FDD (not SCD) with output

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to publish folder with [framework dependent deployments - FDD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index#framework-dependent-deployments-fdd). But as soon as I want to target different directory then default, application is published as [self contained deployments - SCD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index#self-contained-deployments-scd).

This deploy as FDD:

```
dotnet publish -c Release
```

and this as SCD:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o "d:\temp\publish"
```

How can I deploy as FDD and also defined output dir?
I am using .NET Core 2.1.

I also tried (but it's not working):

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o "d:\temp\publish" -f netcoreapp2.1
```

My `.csproj` file is:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    <PackagesRoot>..\</PackagesRoot>
    <SpaRoot>Angular\</SpaRoot>
    <WWWRoot>wwwroot\</WWWRoot>
    <!-- Hides dist folders in wwwroot! -->
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(WWWRoot)dist*\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Status:**

Not sure if this is a bug, but [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9620) is issue on GitHub.

Comment: witch version of .net core are you using?

Comment: @MasihAkbari Sorry, I forget to write version. It is .NET Core 2.1.

Comment: Try this: `dotnet publish -f netcoreapp2.1 -c Release`

Comment: can you put your `csproj` file

Comment: @MasihAkbari Added.

Comment: I don't have 2.1 version it seems ok on 2.0 if you sure about this behavior try post an issue on [dotnet cli github](https://github.com/dotnet/cli)

Comment: the "but it's not working" is probably your real issue here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem occurred when `MSTest Test project (.NET Core)` was added to project.

Solution is to specify target project and not publish entire solution.

This works:

```
dotnet publish ./Hosting/Hosting.csproj -c Release -o d:\temp    //publish project
```

and this not:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o d:\temp   //publish solution
```

[Here is link](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9620#issuecomment-404325204) to additional explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try specifying the framework like the line below:

> dotnet publish -c Release -o "d:/temp/publish" -f netcoreapp2.1

[more info about dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21) and [examples for publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli)

Comment: This is not working. I tried all different combinations.

Comment: @Makla did you try `dotnet publish -f netcoreapp2.1 -c Release`

Comment: The question was hot to publish with -o. This `dotnet publish -c Release -o "d:\temp\publish" -f netcoreapp2.1` is not working.

Comment: @Makla i have dotnet core 2.0 on my system and `dotnet publish -c Release -o "d:/temp/publish" -f netcoreapp2.0` works on my machine. you can post an issue to dotnet core github about this

Comment: No error, I just get all localization dll-s in folder `es, fr, it, pl, ja ...` together with all `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` dll.

Answer (score 0):

The output option works for both options, the difference between a framework-dependent deployment (FDD) and self-contained deployment (SCD) is in the `-r RID` option along with the optional `--self-contained true/false` flag (defaults to `true` when the `-r` option is used).

So you would use this to create a FDD:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o "D:\temp\publish-fdd"
```

and an SCD with:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x65 -o "D:\temp\publish-fdd"
```

If you don't specify the `-o` option, the publish output will be put into the project's `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish` for FDDs or the runtime-specific subfolder `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\win-x64` for SCDs